# How do I wrap a table around an image?

Tags: css, html, web

Using only HTML and CSS, is there a way to accomplish this:

[image]

The cow image is floating to the right.

How can I get the table to properly wrap around the cow image? I've only managed to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can't.  The spec does not allow for this sort of behavior.

Comment: That's why modern web developers use div's; they're more dynamic (other advantages of using divs over tables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html?rq=1)

Comment: Though using css/divs is typical, common, and accepted practice nowadays, there are still many valid reasons to use tables. Which is why sites like http://amazon.com still use them. Not saying they are interchangeable, but that they both serve certain purposes and tables sometimes serve it much more effectively.

Answer (score 3):

You could work with two tables and set the upper table to, e.g. `width: 50%;` and the bottom one to 100%.

**Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KuGES/**

Please note: this is **really** bad practice! Use DIV's instead!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve it by expanding the table.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h1>Title Goes Here</h1></td>
        <td rowspan="3"><img height="200" src="http://pureblissnutrition.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/1238813_26934058.jpg"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</td>
        <td>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</td>
        <td>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</td>
        <td colspan="2">Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</td>
        <td colspan="2">Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/9n7d3/